# Recuperar la IP a través de SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiente Trigger, lo que  sucede es que al querer recuperar la IP de la maquina cliente este toma la IP del Servidor de aplicaciones, algien que pueda ayudar con una manera de recuperar esa ip, no la del servidor de aplicasion.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[InsertLoginControl]
on [dbo].[Attendance]
for insert 
as

declare @noEmpleado varchar(5)
DECLARE @IP_Address varchar(255)
declare @name varchar(50)
declare @pass varchar(50)
declare @LastCon datetime

select top 1 @noEmpleado = EmpNo from Attendance order by idAttendance desc

SELECT @IP_Address = 
convert(varchar(20),CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address'))
select top 1 @name = NameDisplay from Login_empl where 
EmployeeNo=@noEmpleado
select top 1 @pass = UserPAss from Login where Emp_Number=@noEmpleado

select top 1 @LastCon=DateLogout from logincontrol where 
empNumber=@noEmpleado order by id desc

if exists(select empNumber from LoginControl where empNumber= @noEmpleado) 
begin 

if(@LastCon is null)
begin
    update LoginControl set DateLogout=getdate() where empNumber=@noEmpleado
    insert into LoginControl 
 values(@IP_Address,getdate(),null,@noEmpleado,@name,
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BCPPlus2019', @pass))
end

else
begin
    insert into LoginControl 
 values(@IP_Address,getdate(),null,@noEmpleado,@name,
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BCPPlus2019', @pass))
end

end
else
begin 

    insert into LoginControl 
values(@IP_Address,getdate(),null,@noEmpleado,@name, 
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('BCPPlus2019', @pass))

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente para obtener la dirección IP de la computadora que ejecutó el procedimiento almacenado o trigger. Espero que sea de tu ayuda.

```
DECLARE @IP_Address VARCHAR(255);    
SELECT @IP_Address = client_net_address    
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections    
WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;
```